# Insert Server Date to DB ODBC Error

Tags: asp-classic

I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to insert the server date into a DB through the Parameters call, my code for this action is listed below:

```
<%
If (CStr(Request("MM_insert")) = "Modal-Menu-AddNote-Form") Then
  If (Not MM_InsertEdit) Then
    ' execute the insert
    Dim MM_InsertCmd

    Set MM_InsertCmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
    MM_InsertCmd.ActiveConnection = MM_Logistics_STRING
    MM_InsertCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Notes (Note_Text, Note_Date) VALUES (?, ?)" 
    MM_InsertCmd.Prepared = true
    MM_InsertCmd.Parameters.Append MM_InsertCmd.CreateParameter("param1", 202, 1, 255, Request.Form("Modal-Menu-Paragraph-AddNote")) ' adVarWChar
    MM_InsertCmd.Parameters.Append MM_InsertCmd.CreateParameter("param2", 135, 0, -1, Date) ' adDBTimeStamp
    MM_InsertCmd.Execute
    MM_InsertCmd.ActiveConnection.Close

    ' append the query string to the redirect URL
    Dim MM_InsertRedirectUrl
    MM_InsertRedirectUrl = "edit.asp"
    If (Request.QueryString <> "") Then
      If (InStr(1, MM_InsertRedirectUrl, "?", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
        MM_InsertRedirectUrl = MM_InsertRedirectUrl & "?" & Request.QueryString
      Else
        MM_InsertRedirectUrl = MM_InsertRedirectUrl & "&" & Request.QueryString
      End If
    End If
    Response.Redirect(MM_InsertRedirectUrl)
  End If
End If
%>
```

It's important to take note of the "param2" line as this is the area that im trying to insert the date into the DB, I have also tried (0-Unknown,1-In,2-Out,3-In/Out) for the 3rd argument but I still end up getting errors like Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another, or Invalid string or buffer length. Any thoughts or ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e57' 

[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid string or buffer length 

/massmarkets/logistics/edit.asp, line 67 
Which is the line that has the Execute command

Comment: This may sound dumb, but I used to have great success using the nvarchar parameter types for *every* parameter:  `MM_InsertCmd.CreateParameter("param2", 202, 1, 4000, Date())`. OLEDB and SQL Server never had trouble interpreting and converting dates, integers, etc. as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue ended up being resloved, ended up being an issue with my text area that was gathering the data. Closing thread, thank you all for your help and advice.